Facebook Graph API: Products without \"link\" information can't be uploaded
I am trying to send items to commerce catalog using V20 Graph API andI continue to get this error.

"error_user_msg": "Products without \"link\" information can't be uploaded. Please check that this field is included for each product in a separate, labelled column.",

All fields appear to be valid, I just can't get past this error here.
I have tried with API and directly with Graph API Post, both return the same error.
var postData = {
    "retailer_id": "TEST_SKU_12345",  // Using a static SKU for testing
    "name": "Test Product",
    "price": 100,  // Using an integer value for the price
    "currency": "USD",  // Default to USD
    "link": encodeURIComponent("https://store.casablancawirelessllc.com/g-power-5g?sku=PQPWFV"),  // URL-encoded link
    "image_url": "https://b3213372.smushcdn.com/3213372/wp-content/uploads/2023/07/stacks-dark-1.png" // Valid image URL
  };


You have to pass url as a prarameter
Facebook documentation was not well managed , so you face such issue.
Refer this for request params for product-items
